# Eventlistener for form input on iphone?

Tags: iphone

I'm playing around with jQTouch to create a web app on the iPhone.

I'm using the scrolling extension to create the effect of a fixed toolbar on the top of the page while still able to scroll the rest of the page via a scrollable div.

Everything works fine except for when a user pulls up the keyboard in order to fill in form elements in the scrollable div. The whole body is pushed to top and the ugly url bar is shown.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

My partial solution is that I change the height of the scrollable div when the keyboard pops up (which the focus event tells me) and scroll to the top (and reverse this when the blur event occurs).

That's all fine, except that there is the remaining problem that the phone scrolls down after the first character input.